# Git reset to older commit

Tags: git

Hallo to all.

I've got some problems regarding reset to an older commit.

Steps what I do:

1. grep the commit ID to which I would like to return

```
[USER@VM gitrepo]$ git log
commit c846a35cd30fa05a9a125d613b220245f1f7d96e
Author: Tobias  <tobias@xy.de>
Date:   Fri Mar 23 16:00:33 2018 +0100

    test 1 in ccc

commit d567daf9e82b2bb1fa8493757826a224c4f3b96f
Author: Tobias  <tobias.@xy.de>
Date:   Fri Mar 23 15:58:48 2018 +0100

    test 2 hilfe.txt

commit dbef962622cc6bc326bbcccb3e87332af7e9577a
Author: Tobias  <tobias.@xy.de>
Date:   Fri Mar 23 15:54:23 2018 +0100

    test 2 hilfe.txt
```

2. reset the commit and discard all local changes

```
[USER@VM gitrepo]$ git reset --hard dbef962622cc6bc326bbcccb3e87332af7e9577a
HEAD is now at dbef962 test 2 hilfe.txt
```

3. force pushing the commit to the master server and discard all changes on the master

```
[USER@VM gitrepo]$ git push --force
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: From /home/git/gitrepo
remote:  + c846a35...dbef962 master     -> origin/master  (forced update)
remote: Already up-to-date.
To git@VM:/home/git/gitrepo/
 + c846a35...dbef962 master -> master (forced update)
```

Until now everything looks good.

**Now to the Problem:**

On my master server there is a folder called "cleartext". I pull the commits automaticaly (from my master with the hooks - "post-update") to this folder because I use it with my puppet server.

How my post-update looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

### main ###
cd /home/git/cleartext/gitrepo
env -i git pull
env -i git clean -f -d
```

After forcing the push my commit ID's from my client and my "cleartext" client are different. (And furthermore I can't run a git pull on my "cleartext" client)

When I'm deleting the folder on my "cleartext" client and clone the git again there is no problem and the ID's are equal. I don't want to clone them every time.

What am I doing wrong?
How would you reset your local/master git repo to an older commit and discard all changes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw. we only use one branch!

Comment: Why do you only use one branch?

Comment: Because our git is only used for puppet files and if we have several branches it's gonna be a mess. Because we have more than 30 employees across several teams which have different tasks.

Comment: @evolutionxbox how would you reset the master branch to an old commit?

Comment: I would use the reset command `git reset --hard <commit-id>`

Comment: @evolutionxbox how I write on step 2

But why do I get this comment ID conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cleartext client now has newer commits than the remote. This is normal.
To always force checkout the remote and discard what you have locally, just reset there as well.
Change the `env -i git pull` to

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: But the problem that i cant push after the reset still exist, so my cleartext client can't get the data

Comment: @jubimk4 If you hard reset the cleartext client with origin it should work fine.
This is basically the same as deleting the branch and checking out a fresh version. What is the error message you get if you try to push?

Comment: [USER@VM gitrepo]$ git push
To git@VM.baag:/home/git/gitrepo/
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@VM.baag:/home/git/gitrepo/'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: This should not happen if you did what I wrote in the answer. Is your remote branch not master? Or do you use a different remote than origin

Comment: What is the output if you run `git reset --hard origin/master`?

Comment: And when i wanna commit after a git reset --hard :




# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#   (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: output: HEAD is now at XXXXX... 
but this is not the HEAD what I wanna have. It's the head before i did the reset.

Comment: the `origin/master` part is important. just `git reset --hard` will not work. It needs to be `git reset --hard origin/master`. Sorry if this is obvious, just making sure. It should work

Comment: Try with a different repo and see if it works there. Just checkout something, remove some commits, maybe make new ones and than run `git reset --hard origin/master`. It should reset everything to what is on the remote. If this works, we can look into whats different in you repo.

Comment: Already tried it with an other repo. I solved the problem by deleting the cleartext tree. Your setting is now working :) THX! `git fetch` `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: @jubimk4 awesome! Glad I could help. Can you accept the answer please?